# How to check if PeriodicWorkRequest was enqueued?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm queuing periodic task in the following way:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UpdateWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .addTag(WORK_TAG)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(request);
```

How can I check if this periodic task was queued?
I've tried:

```
LiveData<List<WorkStatus>> statusesLiveData = WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag(WORK_TAG);
```

but the list seems to be null all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not observing the LiveData, since no observer, so no values are being emitted, thus null. Update your code as following:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag("[TAG_STRING]").observe(this, listOfWorkStatuses -> {

    WorkStatus workStatus = listOfWorkStatuses.get(0);
    boolean finished = workStatus.getState().isFinished();
    if (!finished) {
        // Work InProgress
    } else {
        // Work Finished
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to observe the `LiveData` to get the value. No value will be emitted if there's no observer for it, which is the feature of `LiveData`.

```
LiveData<List<WorkStatus>> statusesLiveData = WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag(WORK_TAG);
statusesLiveData.observe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
there is actually a way to do this without observing (it should be called from background thread):

```
List<WorkStatus> statusesLiveData = WorkManager.getInstance().synchronous()
                                      .getStatusesByTagSync(WORK_TAG);
```